# how to find and set a new variable using file handling

Tags: python, scripting, expression

Im being passed a filepath through a system argument, 
"Load the pipe-delimited file P. It is organized with 3 fields on each line: firstname|lastname|birthday.
Search for the firstname F and lastname L, replacing the birthday with B. Write the file back out in the same pipe-delimited format."

the question wants you to setup several defined functions to call on, one of them returns an index of F and L and B, and then afterwards youll use a different function to set the birthday to B. in my code, I tried setting the records (to which the filepath is passed to) to a str, because I keep hitting a block on the code saying it cannot add together int, but only str. however this didn't work either.

```
def findIndex(records, firstname, lastname):
    import re
    # Your code goes here:
    search = re.findall(firstname, lastname)
    if search == 0:
        print('value not found')
        return -1
    else:
        return firstname, lastname

def setBirthday(records, index, newBirthday):
    #Your code goes here:
    strecord = str(records)
    chars = len(index[0])
    birthday = records[index + chars:index + chars + 8]
    newBirthday = records.replace(birthday, B)
    return records, index, newBirthday
```

so the first part of the code should find all instances of the values passed to it, and the second part should be able to change the birthday in the deliminated list and change it to a new value (whatever the system passes to it.

so far, ive only been able to get it to find the indexed values of ('John', 'Doe') which should mean that my function for the first is outputting correctly. however when I call on the birthday function it errors out.

Comment: found out, that my else: block in the first function is useless and doesnt do anything, and isn't needed...

Comment: im now thinking that if I can find a way to get the index value of that search, I should be able to pull that list, and then modify the subset element of the list 'birthday' to a new variable. if I can get there, I should be able to write it all back to the file with a new birthday as it wants.